# Magento on MAMP custom module install fails "Unknown database 'magento'"

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have created a custom module, but when I go to run php `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it fails and returns SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'magento'.

I have tried other stackover flow solutions to no avail. And I have uninstalled and reinstalled magento instances.

[image]

**/app/etc.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'e6e76a3bc072a8ccf6c12282b78db401'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'files'
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Fri, 22 Mar 2019 20:36:14 +0000'
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you get it working?

From what I can see your .env is just referencing the wrong port number for mysql.

Try this (change the host to localhost:8889):

```
'default' => [
    'host' => 'localhost:8889',
    'dbname' => 'magento',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'active' => '1'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling the command this by explicitly calling the path to my version of PHP: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade`